# PHP ZipArchive->close() is crazy slow

Tags: php, zip

I am using ZipArchive to incrementally zip a site. I call the script multiple times to ensure it doesn't exceed to php max execution time.

This works fine on most web hosts. However for some hosts, calling close() on the archive is incredibly slow and results in the execution time being exceeded.

For example, on one host with a 30 second max execution time, I zip for 20 seconds and then call close but it does not make it in time.

I have tried PCLZip as an alternative. It is reliable but it is shockingly slow in comparison.

Any ideas on why it behaves this way and how it could be worked around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `fopen`/`fwrite`/`fclose` over ftp for example. You'll notice `fopen` and `fclose` take a while to execute while `fwrite` is instant.

You might say "that can't be right" `fwrite` sends the data over ftp everytime. I don't know if it does or not but i bet it doesn't and `fclose` sends all the batch work.

In a simmilar fashion `ZipArchive::close` may be finishing up everything you've structured till then and merging it into the final file.

Comment: Yes, it must be. Though it is strange how differently it behaves on different hosts. I got around it by closing the zip every 100 records to spread the close time out.

Comment: That's what I've done in a simmilar situation but i wasn't constrained by execution time (I could change that) i was affected by memory_limit.

Comment: So does it means, we have to get stuck with a slow zipping of files with php still in 2015? Because, I am still facing the same problem still.

Comment: @andex -- this is not a PHP problem or even an "old problem". This is a Zip problem (Zip file design to be precise).

Comment: AFAIK when you zip multiple files into an archive the end-result will contain a header and a body. The body has all of the archived/compressed files. The header contains a list of all of the files inside the body. Every time you `ZipArchive::close` a file you are basically rewriting its header and a part of its body.

Comment: Imagine opening a Zip archive and adding 50 files to the archive, closing it, reopening it and adding 50 more files and so on repeated 100 times. The whole process will take quite a lot on any kind of hardware/software platform.

Comment: If that is the case, why is zipping files using windows built-in GUI Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder fast?

Comment: Allocate the same amount of CPU+RAM to your hosting server and issue a single call to add all your files (like addGlob or addPattern) with all of the files in one go and it will likely have comparable time.